# Database design

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Our database is part of a (specialized) desktop application. 
The primary goal is to keep data about certain **events**.

**Events** happen every few minutes.

The data collected about **events** changes frequently with new data groups being added in and old ones swapped out almost monthly (the data comes in definite groups).

I have to put together a database to track the events. A first stab at that might be to simply have a single big table where each row is an event and that is basically what our data looks like, but this seems undesirable because of our constantly changing groups of data (i.e. the number of columns would either keep growing perpetually or we would constantly having this months database incompatible with last months database - ugh!). Because of this I am leadning toward the following even  though it creates circular  references. (But maybe this is a stupid idea)

Create tables like

Table Events
Table Group of the Month 1
Table Group of the Month 2
...

Table Events has:
A primary key whose deletion cascade to delete rows with foreign keys referencing it
A nullable foreighn key for each data group table

Each data group table has:
A primary key, whose deletion cascades to null out foreign keys referencing it
Columns for the data in that group
A non-nullable foreign key back to the event

This still leaves you with a growing, changing Event Table (as you need to add new foreign key columns for each new data group), just much less drastically. However it seems more modular to me than one giant table. Is this a good solution to this situation? If not, what is?

Any suggestions?

P.S. We are using SQL Express or SQL Compact (we are currently experimenting with which one suits us best)

Comment: Almost entirely straight numerical data. Just a column or two contain text. Everything else is raw numerical data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have foreign keys for each data group table in the event table.

The event table already has an event_id which is in each data group table.  So you can get from event to the child tables.  Furthermore there will be old rows in the event table that are not in the latest data group table.  So you really can't have a foreign key.

That said, I would wonder whether there is additional structure in the data group tables that can be used to clean up your design.  Without knowing anything about what they look like I can't say.  But if there is, consider taking advantage of it!  (A schema that changes every month is a pretty bad code smell.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use basically the single table approach and store the changing event data as XML in an XML column? You can even use XSD schemas to account for the changing data types, and you can add indexes on XML data if fast query performance on some XML data is required.

A permanently changing DB schema wouldn't really be an option if I were to implement such a database.

Answer (score 0):

Store your data at as granular a level as possible. It might be as simple as:

EventSource int FK
EventType int FK
Duration int
OccuredOn datetime

Get the data right and as simple as possible in the first place, and then

1. Aggregate via views or queries. Your instincts are correct about the ever changing nature of the columns - better to control that in T-SQL than in DDL.
2. I faced this problem a number of years ago with logfiles for massive armies of media players, and where I ultimately ended up was taking this data and creating a OLAP cube out of it. OLAP is another approach to database design where the important thing is optimizing it for reporting and "sliceability". It sounds like you're on that track, where it would be very useful to be able to look at a quick month's view of data, then a quarter's, and then back down to a week's. This is what OLAP is for.

Microsoft's technology for this is Analysis Services, which comes as part of Sql Server. If you didn't want to take the entire plunge (OLAP has a pretty steep learning curve), you could also look at doing a selectively denormalized database that you populated each night with ETL from your source database.

HTH.

Comment: Key phrase in the OLAP approach here: "time dimension".

Comment: Note that Analysis Services [are not part of the SQL Server Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365248.aspx) (or Compact) editions.

Comment: Ah yes...good point - I always forget that. For those, you'll need to get Developer, which is selling for about $50 on Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Developer-Edtn-2008-32-bit-English/dp/B003KWQBQ2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1297191013&sr=8-1.